# slow log contains query, but query time is less than long_query_time

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

```
mysql> select @@long_query_time;
+-------------------+
| @@long_query_time |
+-------------------+
|          2.000000 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@log_queries_not_using_indexes
    -> ;
+---------------------------------+
| @@log_queries_not_using_indexes |
+---------------------------------+
|                               0 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but the slow query log contains:

```
# Query_time: 1.000111  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0 SET timestamp=1559116596; select sleep(1);
```

Is there any other variable that affects this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add to my.cnf ( or my.ini )

min_examined_row_limit=1

the line should be omitted in the slow query log - in this case, no rows were examined.

Comment: tks for reply!  min_examined_row_limit:Queries that examine fewer than this number of rows are not logged to the slow query log. when i set this variable  min_examined_row_limit=0 means log all query? but regardless the variable log_query_time?

Comment: I have found there are some instances where the slow query log is 'littered' with this type information and long_query_time appears to be ignored when the decision is made to 'log' this type of query.  With min_examined_row_limt=1 it most likely will NOT be listed in the slow query log.

Comment: yes,it works but still  puzzle ,thk you !